# Ubuntu 20.04 System doesn't recognize external microphone

Tags: sound, 20.04

My ubuntu 20.04 doesn't recognizes external mic with combo jack entry microphone, i nearly tried everything. Here are some information and things i did.

My codec for sound `cat /proc/asound/card1/codec* | grep Codec`

```
Codec: Realtek ALC269VC
```

`sudo lshw -c sound` shows this;

```
*-multimedia:0            
   description: Audio device
   product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:33 memory:f7a14000-f7a17fff
*-multimedia:1
       description: Audio device
       product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f7a10000-f7a13fff
```

Cards that i have with `pacmd list-cards`

```
index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
            alsa.card = "0"
            alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
            alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7a14000 irq 33"
            alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
            device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
            sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
            device.bus = "pci"
            device.vendor.id = "8086"
            device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
            device.product.id = "0c0c"
            device.product.name = "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller"
            device.form_factor = "internal"
            device.string = "0"
            device.description = "Built-in Audio"
            module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
            device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

Things i added to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=basic 
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1
```

Model is basic but i tried a lot of things then i found my codecs model in the [official documentation of Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto)

I tried overriding jack from `hdajackretask` but when i change something from there i always get the `tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/reconfig: Device or resource is busy` even when im not running anything on my system(videos, sound etc.)

Is there any other way to solve this or should i buy a jack to usb transformer?

Comment: I fixed the problem by moving to arch linux, lol.

Answer (score 0):

- To apply change from hdajackrestask, you must stop pulseaudio autospawn and kill it:

`mkdir ~/.pulse`
`echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
`pulseaudio -k`

(`echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf`    to revert)

- Did you tried these 5 models in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, instead of "basic" you tried
  (hum, reboot after each test is better):

  - headset-mic
  - headset-mode
  - alc269vb-amic
  - alc269vb-dmic
  - alc269-dmic

Comment: Hello @laugeo thanks for such a kind response, and i'm sorry for answering it lately  but hdajackretask keeps throwing the same error, i disabled the autospawn, also i tried rebooting after changing autospawn but it didn't work either

Comment: to check if a process lock sound device: `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*`  : should return nothing

Comment: I'm facing the same problem (also ubuntu 20.04, on two different computers) when trying to use HDAJackRetask. Apparently the `autospawn=no` does not prevent pulseaudio from respawning.

Comment: you must also close alsmixer and other audio app, use fuser command to see the pb, alternatively rename pulseaudio  program: `sudo mv /usr/bin/pulseaudio /usr/bin/pulseaudio-disabled`      (rename back when finished of course)

Comment: @0x539 did you find anything? i tried with three different computers on 18.04 it was working , but on 20.04 it doesn't works.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci @laugeo there is not other process blocking `/dev/snd/`, somehow `autospawn=no` doesn't prevent pulseaudio from respawning in 20.04. Moving the pulseaudio binary as @laugeo suggests works though (no more `Device of resource busy` error). However in this situation HDAJackRetask freezes when clicking "Apply now" and when shutting down I get a message along the lines of `waiting for process tee`. After this any process which should play audio (vlc, `speaker-test`, etc.) gives errors and doesn't work.